# Integration tests in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Rust doc defines that an integration test is something that verifies if a library's components all work together. Is that a semantical definition of what an integration test is?
I ask that because in a microservices environment where a bunch of Rust microservices exist, can I have my own `integration tests` under the `tests` directory which not just test all the components that make up my microservice but also do some integration tests with other microservices?

In essence, can integration tests that involve interaction with other microservices be run using "cargo test"

I checked Rust documentation and tried some basic `integration` tests.

Comment: You can do anything in integration tests, but typically, libraries are setup so that if someone clones the repo and runs `cargo test`, everything will pass, maybe with some external libraries or environment variables if they are essential. This is mostly opinion-based. Rust and Cargo do not prefer or require anything in this area, only that the tests are working rust code.

Comment: Can I use some tests that rely on mocking services to "test' integration? I am wondering, why are they called integration tests? The definition is so generic I am having hard time applying the context to it.

Comment: Rust uses the term to differentiate them from unit tests. I think it makes more sense when your library can be used to do some simple, std-only operations, like string manipulation, sorting, math/physics, or type stuff.